# crystal report parameters

Tags: crystal-reports

I use the following code to pass parameters into a CR

```
    //  Reuse myDiscreteValue, and assign second country
    myParam = new ParameterField();
    myDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    myParam.Name = "@toDate";
    myDiscreteValue.Value = RmtUtility.Utility.DisplayDate(toDate);
    myParam.CurrentValues.Add(myDiscreteValue);
    myParams.Add(myParam);
```

I get an error message "Missing Parameter Value" when I tried to export the document using CR Option.

:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing and then setting the values of the parameters within the Report object.

Something like this:

```
ParameterDiscreteValue paramDV = new ParameterDiscreteValue(); 
paramDV.Value = RmtUtility.Utility.DisplayDate(toDate);
report.ParameterFields["@toDate"].CurrentValues.Clear(); 
report.ParameterFields["@toDate"].DefaultValues.Clear();
report.ParameterFields["@toDate"].CurrentValues.Add(paramDV);
```

Note: `report` being your Crystal Report Document